# How to detect a Process Exit from a DLL in C#

Tags: c#, dll, process, exit

I have a WPF Application that is calling functions inside a native DLL (written in c++).
This functions in the .DLL sometimes do a Process Exit that is killing the WPF application.

Example:

```
WPF App:
.....
[DllImport("native.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern void NativeMethod();
.....
void CallFunction()
{
  //Call the native function
  NativeMethod();
}
....
```

Inside the NativeMethod there is an exit and I cannot change the source code of the .dll.
Anyone know a way to capture this exit in the DLL from .NET code ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: There's nothing you can do about this except one thing.  Throw away the DLL.

Comment: Hi Hans,
Well there are some solutions even if they are not perfect... I can create a simple console application has a proxy to the .dll so will kill the console app process and not the main process... so there are some solutions..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AppDomain.ProcessExitOk, the problem using AppDomain's was they only work with .NET assemblies :( so I had to create an assembly that loads my native DLL via P/Invoke.  Once I had that, I could Load the assembly in a different AppDomin and call the functions of the native .dll throw managed .dll. I capture the AppDomain.ProcessExit event from the AppDomain and I could capture the exit ;).

Thanks aiampogi for the idea ;)

Answer (score 2):

On top of my head, the only thing I can think of is load that DLL to a process/app domain (more on an appdomain) then invoke that method and register for the ProcessExit event to handle it properly.

I might try to do this later but I'm just not sure if you can invoke static methods on an appdomain or invoke a non-serialized class method on an appdomain.

Comment: Hi aiampogi,
Thanks for your feedback, do you have any code that I can start with ? I will keep looking with your idea since seems better one.
Thanks

Comment: Figured you already did it. Congrats! Glad I was able to help you out.